# Python to get video transcript, rename video files what's in the transcript?

Tags: python, video, batch-rename, transcription, google-cloud-speech

I have thousands of very short video clips that are one sentence or one word long and I need to rename them according to a naming convention (ESL learning orientated).

Here's a small example of what's said inside the video files:

```
Vid_12344.mp4
"Apple, apple."
Vid_12345.mp4
"I like apples."
Vid_12346.mp4
"Do you like apples?"
Vid_12347.mp4
"She likes apples."
```

I want to create a script that loops through each clip, gets the transcript, and then renames the files the first 200 characters of the transcript.  It would be nice if the transcripts were stripped of punctuation and instead of spaces there was "_" instead.

Continuing with the example above Python would have an output of the following:

```
Vid_12344.mp4 >> Apple_apple.mp4
Vid_12345.mp4 >> I_like_apples.mp4
Vid_12346.mp4 >> Do_you_like_apples.mp4
Vid_12347.mp4 >> She_likes_apples.mp4
```

The transcript doesn't need to be exact, I just don't want to have to click on every single one of these...

I've taken a couple of Python classes on Coursera and understand loops and have done a simple API with twitter but this one is really out of my league.  I know it's possible and I've seen what looks to be some of the pieces of what I would need to do but I'm just having a real hard time putting it together mentally.

Comment: You can try to use Google speech recognition API -- they have nice tutorials there: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/rest-tutorial